# CoverFlow- Flip when selected

Tags: iphone, coverflow

i am working on an application which uses the iPod like application in iPhone.. I have implemented the Coverflow. But the main problem now is when we select any image it must flip and then i have to display the detail of that image... and when clicked on detail it must flip again and the same image must get displayed... Working on this from a long but still no success.. Please help.. Thanx in advance.. 
Note: if the question is unclear or if u want any code regarding please ask i will post it over her..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the images you should use content views in the flow, that show images or details and can flip between both. How that can be done is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755492/how-to-implement-an-iphone-view-transition-animation-with-both-flipping-and-scali/1755608#1755608).

Comment: but i am using Alex Fajkowski openFlow... dont knw from where to set the animation as discussed above. please help. I have used his code as it is with the same nib file and have changed the images array only...

Comment: You have to manipulate Alex' code. Main thing is to change the AFOpenFlowView in a way that the dictionaries can contain not only images, but UIViews or even better just objects which have something like a thumbnail property which is displayed in the flow. It's not that hard, you just have to change the code wherever the images from coverImages or onscreenCovers or whatever is accessed.

Comment: thanks kai for your support but as it was much urgent so i have started implementing the jukebox for the same... lets keep the fingers crossed.. Please have a look at this code and see if you can flip these images or not.. http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=295..
Thanks