# Page flip transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, transition, xib, flip

I was wondering how to turn this code into a page transition.  I want to switch Xibs with this page flipping affect. Thanks!

### .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface PageOpenAnimationTutorialViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *openPageButton;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *pageImage;
}

- (IBAction) openPage:(id)sender;
- (void) pageOpenView:(UIView *)viewToOpen duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

@end
```

### .m:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction) openPage:(id)sender {
    [self pageOpenView:pageImage duration:1.0f];
}

- (void) pageOpenView:(UIView *)viewToOpen duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
    // Remove existing animations before stating new animation
    [viewToOpen.layer removeAllAnimations];

    // Make sure view is visible
    viewToOpen.hidden = NO;

    // disable the view so it’s not doing anythign while animating
    viewToOpen.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    // Set the CALayer anchorPoint to the left edge and
    // translate the button to account for the new
    // anchorPoint. In case you want to reuse the animation
    // for this button, we only do the translation and
    // anchor point setting once.
    if (viewToOpen.layer.anchorPoint.x != 0.0f) {
        viewToOpen.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
        viewToOpen.center = CGPointMake(viewToOpen.center.x - viewToOpen.bounds.size.width/2.0f, viewToOpen.center.y);
    }
    // create an animation to hold the page turning
    CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    transformAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    transformAnimation.duration = duration;
    transformAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    // start the animation from the current state
    transformAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
    // this is the basic rotation by 90 degree along the y-axis
    CATransform3D endTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3.141f/2.0f,
                                                           0.0f,
                                                           -1.0f,
                                                           0.0f);
    // these values control the 3D projection outlook
    endTransform.m34 = 0.001f;
    endTransform.m14 = -0.0015f;
    transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:endTransform];
    // Create an animation group to hold the rotation
    CAAnimationGroup *theGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];

    // Set self as the delegate to receive notification when the animation finishes
    theGroup.delegate = self;
    theGroup.duration = duration;
    // CAAnimation-objects support arbitrary Key-Value pairs, we add the UIView tag
    // to identify the animation later when it finishes
    [theGroup setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:viewToOpen.tag] forKey:@"viewToOpenTag"];
    // Here you could add other animations to the array
    theGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:transformAnimation, nil];
    theGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    // Add the animation group to the layer
    [viewToOpen.layer addAnimation:theGroup forKey:@"flipViewOpen"];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag 
{
    // Get the tag from the animation, we use it to find the
    // animated UIView
    NSNumber *tag = [theAnimation valueForKey:@"viewToOpenTag"];
    // Find the UIView with the tag and do what you want
    // This only searches the first level subviews
    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        if (subview.tag == [tag intValue]) {
            // Code for what's needed to happen after
            // the animation finishes goes here.
            if (flag) {
                // Now we just hide the animated view since
                // animation.removedOnCompletion is not working
                // in animation groups. Hiding the view prevents it
                // from returning to the original state and showing.
                subview.hidden = YES;
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you understand and what do you not? Or was your first thought, "Let's ask someone on SO to do this for me"?

Comment: I'm new to the iPhone SDK.. so I tired watching some tutorials, and I even tried to take the code apart and see which each element did.  But it was just too confusing.  As of now I have my Xib's changing with this transition: 

.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

I was wondering if there was a way to make my Xib's flip like a book. Not a page curl. Just a simple flip.

Thanks!

Comment: @zachdrago: Ok, then the answer is that this question is much too big. It's almost like you're asking others to write your program for you. Try to break down the problem into smaller steps, and try to find answers to each of those little problems. Almost all of them are probably already answered on SO.

Comment: @zachdrago: The confusing thing is that you ask "how to turn this code into a page transition", but it seems that the code already creates a page transition. So it's more a matter of you don't know how to use the code? Or how to make it work with Interface Builder? Again, try to ask many small questions instead of one big.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out, [how to implement an iPhone view transition animation with both flipping and scaling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755492/how-to-implement-an-iphone-view-transition-animation-with-both-flipping-and-scali/1755608#1755608) kai1968 is gave a really good answer.

But you should make small changes in your code, and also you will be need to know that how to load view with xib, you can take a look [How to load a View using a nib file created with Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/iphone-how-to-load-a-view-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder/866261#866261).

Hope this helps.